# Парсинг сложного Json в List

Tags: java, массивы, json, коллекции, arraylist

Дан вот такой Json-файл. Как добавить в коллекцию простой элемент в курсе, а вот как в коллекцию сунуть коллекцию, да ещё и сортировать его по одному из элементов я не в силах.

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "hostid": "10106",
      "host": "Yandex DNS",
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "interfaceid": "9",
          "ip": "77.88.8.8"
        },
        {
          "interfaceid": "13",
          "ip": "77.88.8.8"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "hostid": "10106",
      "host": "Yandex DNS",
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "interfaceid": "6",
          "ip": "77.88.8.8"
        },        
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Индекс коллекции должен совпадать со значением переменной interfaceid (это значение уникальное).

Comment: А зачем в коллекцию засовывать саму коллекцию, а не ее элементы? Не понятно что должно быть на выходе, чего добиваетесь? Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Не оно https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md?

Answer (score 2):

Тут две задачи.

1. Превратить JSON в Java-объекты;
2. Отсортировать полученные объекты по нужному критерию.

Для решения первой задачи можно использовать [Google GSON](https://habrahabr.ru/company/naumen/blog/228279/). Эта библиотека позволяет конвертировать JSON в Java-объекты и обратно. Кроме Google GSON существуют и другие библиотеки, такие как [Jackson итд](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/280782/).

Для решения второй задачи создайте класс, который реализует [интерфейс Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

В этом классе реализуйте метод `compare(T o1, T o2)`, который будет сравнивать два объекта из вашего JSON и возвращать `1`, если первый объект *больше* второго, `0` - если объекты равны и `-1` если первый объект *меньше* второго.

После чего отсортируйте массив объектов, который вы получили из JSON с помощью вашего [класса-компаратора](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html), вызвав метод [Collections.sort(list, comparator)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-), где list - это ваш список объектов из JSON, а comparator - это ваша реализация интерфейса `Comparator`.

Есть и [другой способ](http://echuprina.blogspot.ru/2012/02/comparable-comparator.html) вместо создания отдельного компаратора. Это объявление объектов, список которых вы генерируете из JSON как `Comparable`. В таком случае вам надо будет реализовать в классе метод `compareTo(T obj)`, который будет сравнивать текущий экземпляр класса с переданным в параметре (`obj`). После чего вызываете метод [Collections.sort(list)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-), где list - это список объектов, полученных из JSON, в котором каждый объект реализует интерфейс `Comparable`.