# Парсинг json в java (массив в массиве)

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Пытался вот парсить json-файл. Этот список позже нужно пихнуть в адаптер на Android. Но пока проблема в парсинге. Сложность в том, что тут массив в массиве. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/652234/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-json-%D0%B2-list) (это старый код, но тот же json-файл) не очень помогли. Вот что я хотел сделать:

[image: Описание действий]

Json:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "hostid": "10106",
      "host": "Yandex DNS",
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "interfaceid": "9",
          "ip": "77.88.8.8"
        },
        {
          "interfaceid": "13",
          "ip": "77.88.8.8"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "hostid": "10106",
      "host": "Yandex DNS",
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "interfaceid": "6",
          "ip": "77.88.8.8"
        },        
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

А это код:

```
public class Main {

    private static String json; //тут json

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ParseJson parseJson = new ParseJson();
        parseJson.parse(json);

        List<ObjectsOfParse> resultParse = parseJson.getCompleteParse();

        for (int i = 0; i < resultParse.size(); i++) {

            List<String[]> aaa = resultParse.get(i).getHostAndHostId();

            System.out.println("hostid = " + aaa.get(i)[0]);
            System.out.println("host = " + aaa.get(i)[1]);

            List<String[]> bbb = resultParse.get(i).getInterfasesList();
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < bbb.get(i).length; i1++) {
                System.out.println("interfacesid = " + bbb.get(i1)[0]);
                System.out.println("ip = " + bbb.get(i1)[1]);
            }
            System.out.println("-----------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ParseJson {

    private List<ObjectsOfParse> completeParse = new ArrayList<ObjectsOfParse>();
    public List<ObjectsOfParse> getCompleteParse() {
        return completeParse;
    }
    public void setCompleteParse(List<ObjectsOfParse> completeParse) {
        this.completeParse = completeParse;
    }

    private ObjectsOfParse objectsOfParse = new ObjectsOfParse();

    public void parse(String json) {
        List<String> hostidList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> hostList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<List> interfacesList = new ArrayList<>();

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);

        JSONArray array = jsonObj.getJSONArray("result");

        // looping through All Contacts
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

            String hostid = jsonObject.getString("hostid");
            String host = jsonObject.getString("host");

            objectsOfParse.addHostidAndHost(hostid, host); 

            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("interfaces");
            for (int i1 = 0; i1 < jsonArray.length(); i1++) {
                jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i1);
                String interfaceid = jsonObject.getString("interfaceid");
                String ip = jsonObject.getString("ip");

                objectsOfParse.addInterfaces(interfaceid,ip);  
            }   

            completeParse.add(objectsOfParse);   
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ObjectsOfParse {

    private List<String[]> interfasesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<String[]> hostAndHostId = new ArrayList<>();
    private String host, hostid;   

    public ObjectsOfParse() {}

    public List<String[]> getHostAndHostId() {
        return hostAndHostId;
    }
    public void setHostAndHostId(List<String[]> hostAndHostId) {
        this.hostAndHostId = hostAndHostId;
    }
    public List<String[]> getInterfasesList() {
        return interfasesList;
    }
    public void setInterfasesList(List<String[]> interfasesList) {
        this.interfasesList = interfasesList;
    }
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
    public String getHostid() {
        return hostid;
    }
    public void setHostid(String hostid) {
        this.hostid = hostid;
    }

    public void addInterfaces(String interfacesid, String ip){
        String[] interfArray = {interfacesid, ip};
        interfasesList.add(interfArray);
    }

    public void addHostidAndHost(String hostid, String host){
        String[] interfArray = {hostid, host};
        hostAndHostId.add(interfArray);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Не понятно в чем собственно проблема

Comment: Но я вам точно скажу что 
private ObjectsOfParse objectsOfParse = new ObjectsOfParse(); 
нельзя делать полем класса. Она у вас постоянно перезаписывается. А вообще вы объясните суть вашей проблемы чтобы получить какую то помощь. Но по идее если вы пренесете инциализацию ObjectsOfParse в метод парс и у вас нет касяков в парсинге, то все заработает.
P.S. А ещё у вас не валидный json;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используем библиотеку `Gson` (https://github.com/google/gson)

Нужно создать аналогичную json-у объектную модель (модификаторы доступа, геттеры и сеттеры опустил для экономии):

```
class Result {
    List<Host> result;
}

class Host {
    String hostid;
    String host;
    List<Interface> interfaces;
}

class Interface {
    String interfaceid;
    String ip;
}
```

Парсим json:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Result result = gson.fromJson(YOUR_JSON, Result.class);
```

Используем объект `result` так, как хотим.