# Как извлечь string в textView из ответа сервера json android?

Tags: android, retrofit

У меня в приложении я работаю с сервером, ответы которого приходят в json формате. Я много видел разных вариантов извлечения string из ответа сервера. Мне нужно сделать что-то приблизительно такого - есть куча строк в ответе сервера и в каждой строке есть какая-то переменная и ее значение: например токены, время на сервере или когда истекает ключ. И вот я хочу извлечь все эти переменные с их значениями хотя-бы в textView в лучшем случае. Сначала мне попался вполне рабочий вариант, но там в интерфейсе вместо call использовали observable, у меня такой вариант не прижился, дальше я наткнулся на библиотеку rxjava. Сначала я добавил зависимости в градл а дальше в mainactivity в инициализации retrofit добавил этот конвертер, но дальше у меня дело почему-то не продвинулось. 
Возможный дубликат моего вопроса не решил мою проблему, так как я на данный момент не работаю с массивом, а только со строками.
Так-же я пробовал своими костыльными способами, типа:

```
 if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Post submitted to API.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SecondScreen.class);
                    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#1cd000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                    //startActivity(intent);
                    saveData();

                    TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.access_token);

                    try {
                        Response<Post> rp = call.execute();
                        txt.setText((CharSequence) rp.body());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                   /* Post post = response.body();
                    txt.append(post.toString()+"\n");*/

                    //txt.setText("onSuccess" + response.body().toString());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Unable to submit post to API.Error!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    findViewById(R.id.btn_submit).getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                }
```

они тоже не помогли... Я видел что вроде есть возможность извлечь данные string из json ответа при помощи стандартных методов GsonConverter.
Класс post:

```
public class Post {
    @SerializedName("username")
    private String username;
    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public Post(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

На данный момент у меня такая инициализация моего ретрофита и логов:

```
HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://сервер/")
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        APIService mAPIService = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
```

Каким приходит  ответ:

```
07-30 06:30:26.730 com.example.developer_4.test_login D/OkHttp: --> POST сервер
    Content-Type: application/json
    Content-Length: 45
07-30 06:30:26.731 com.example.developer_4.test_login D/OkHttp: {"password":"пароль","username":"логин"}
    --> END POST (45-byte body)
07-30 06:30:26.948 com.example.developer_4.test_login D/OkHttp: <-- 200 сервер (216ms)
    Date: Mon, 30 Jul 2018 13:03:03 GMT
    Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
    Content-Length: 397
    P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI ADM DEV COM NAV OUR STP"
    Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
    Connection: Keep-Alive
    Content-Type: application/json
    {"refresh_token": токен", "access_token": токен", "expires_in": 1532957583}
    <-- END HTTP (397-byte body)
```

Если кто знает как решить мою проблему, буду очень рад вашей помощи и советам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Парсинг json в java (массив в массиве)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/655710/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-json-%d0%b2-java-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5)

Comment: Немного не понятно, в чем проблема, у Вас не получается разпарсить JSON правильно?

Comment: у меня вообще не получается разпарсить json никаким из известных мне способов, я перебрал много способов, но ни один из них не работает.

Comment: `Response<Post> rp = call.execute();` - это где, в `onResponse` что-ли? Конечно не получится синхронный поход в сеть в главном потоке, во-первых , использовать один экземпляр `call` для запроса повторно нельзя, во-вторых. Что за класс `Post` и как выглядит `json` с токенами - собственно Вы не показали главного. Я правильно понимаю, что приведённый код - это `onResponse` на запрос логина?

Comment: да вы правильно поняли, сейчас дополню вопрос классом post и json.

Comment: Ну так для ответа Вы должны сделать класс по этому `json`у и везде, где у Вас `Call<Post>` для логина и в коллбеке его запроса - поменять `<Post>` на новый <класс>. `Post` у Вас только `@Body` запроса и больше нигде он не нужен.

Comment: то есть если например мне нужно из ответа извлечь access_token то мне нужно создать класс в котором мы будем запрашивать только этот токен, с конструктором и гетером/сетером, и потом его юзать в ответе?

Comment: Не только этот а все поля - они же уже пришли. Всё так же как и в классе `Post`, только имена и типы полей в соответствии с целевым json'ном

Comment: я понял, то есть если мне нужно что-то получить данные из json то нужно просто создавать такой-же класс как и запрос только уже ответ.

Comment: Не такой как запрос, а такой как ответ - сначала мы конвертируем json в POJO и вставляем его в код, а в рантайме уже Gson конвертирует в наш POJO конкретные данные

Comment: ок спасибо огромное за ответ))

Comment: а вот у меня еще вопрос появился, большая-ли разница в простом Call<class> и Call<List<class>>? а то я честно сказать ее не очень вижу))

Comment: Ровно такая же как и разница между `class` и `List<class>` - первый `Call` должен вернуть один объект типа `class` - второй список таких объектов.